When mounting with X-mount.idmap, what is the format for the user namespace file?
The mount manpage states for the X-mount.idmap option:
•   A user can specify the ID-mapping directly.

    [...]
    
•   A user can specify a user namespace file.

    The user namespace will then be attached to the mount and the ID-mapping of
    the user namespace will become the ID-mapping of the mount.

    For example, X-mount.idmap=/proc/PID/ns/user will attach the user namespace of
    the process PID to the mount.

However, I did not find any reference to the file format, or any actual examples of such files. user_namespaces (7) has something on uid_map and gid_map files, which looks related, but seems to assume uid and gid maps in two separate files, while mount seems to use one file.
Where is the file format documented?
Can I use the same id-type:id-mount:id-host:id-range stanzas I would use when specifying the ID mapping directly, but place them in a file instead? Can I use newlines instead of spaces as separators? Does the format support comments and empty lines?

The "user namespace file" referred to is not a text file you can edit, but a symbolic link in the /proc/ filesystem that is generated by the kernel. For example, ls -l /proc/self/ns/user shows you lrwxrwxrwx  ... /proc/self/ns/user -> 'user:[4026531837]'. This is just a handle to that existing namespace, to use if you want to copy its mappings into another newly created namespace.

I have seen these files (though none of them were readable or had any content). Would I be able to use a static text file stored somewhere in the filesystem instead, say, /etc/mnt.extdisk.idmap? If so, what format would the file follow? (Or where would I be able to find a user namespace file with actual content, so I can examine it?)
